# Using C# 3 (.NET 3.5) for ASCX and ASPX files in SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-part

In an OOTB SharePoint 2010 Server installation, if you use C# 3 in your code-in-front, it doesn't compile, since the C# 2 compiler is used to compile the markup. (At least for me - SharePoint 2010 Server on Windows 7).

So **how do you enable the use of C# 3 and .NET 3.5 for ASCX and ASPX** files in SharePoint 2010? If I use `var` or extension methods, my web parts and page layouts won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2010, despite being "built on .NET 3.5", requires modifications to the web.config of any Web Application that should compile controls and layouts using .NET 3.5.

These modifications can either be applied directly to the web.config file of the Web Application, or one of the two SharePoint methods for web.config modifications can be used:

- Using the `copyappbincontent` stsadm command, [in combination with a web.config merge file](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=432574531450&comments&ref=mf)
- Using the [SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification%28v=office.12%29.aspx) classes

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's not working and what you need to modify in the web.config?? I've not yet experienced any issues with this for any of my SP2010 projects!

Comment: In an OOTB SharePoint 2010 Server installation, if you use C# 3 in your code-in-front, it doesn't compile, since the C# 2 compiler is used to compile the markup. At least for me.

Answer (score 1):

Won't compile?? Are you referring to Visual Studio Error OR Runtime Error?

SharePoint 2010 is based on .net 3.5 and it will work fine.

if it's Visual Studio change the project framework to 3.5

Comment: Runtime error, when SharePoint is trying to load the user control. Everything looks fine in Visual Studio; the project framework version is 3.5 and everything "compiles" from a Visual Studio point of view. The error doesn't appear until the control is actually loaded by SharePoint.